# Comparator circuit outputs error when equal Logisim

Tags: logical-operators, circuit

For a homework assignment I'm supposed to implement a basic one bit comparator which will be used in a larger circuit to compare two 4 bit numbers. I've implemented the one bit comparator but on the larger circuit, when the 4 bit values are equal the circuit outputs error. When one of the 4 bit values is larger than the other the circuit behaves as intended.

[image: The one bit Comparator]

[image: The 4 bit Comparator using One bit comparator chips]

The first image shows my one bit comparator. The second image shows the 4bit comparator.

I'm wondering why it's outputting error when the circuit is equal to each other.

**Note:** I forgot to label the outputs on the 4 bit comparator circuit. However, the outputs are the same as that of the 1 bit comparator. Greater than (gt) on the furthest up, Equal (eq) in the middle and Less than (lt) on the bottom

Comment: Just eyeballing the circuit, it looks OK.  I'll bet Logisim is being goofy--it sometimes is.

Comment: @WayneConrad yeah I thought so too. I'm very new to this and was unsure but I don't see why it shouldn't work

Comment: Does tying `cg0` and `cl0` to logic-low make a difference?

Comment: It did! I had to create another circuit for a 5bit comparator for a signed integer and the circuit worked perfectly